# Error al sumar array con datos double

Tags: java, array, double

***El codigo mas abajo ya funciona como debe ser, por si alguien le quiere dar uso, le agradezco nuevamente a todos los que comentaron***

Dando álgebra linear me están enseñando operaciones con vectores y para simplificarme la vida quise hacer un código para esto, no soy muy diestro con el código aun. Navegando en Internet me encontré con esto para el lenguaje java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OperacionVectores{
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    //Variables k seran el tamaño de los vectores
    int v1,v2,v3;
    System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del vector 1: ");
    v1=sc.nextInt();
    //creamos el primer vector con el tamaño de v1
    double vec1[]=new double[v1];
    //recorremos el vector v1 para llenarlo
    for(int i1=0;i1<vec1.length;i1++){
        System.out.print("\n ingrese el numero de la posicion "+i1+":");
        vec1[i1]=sc.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.print("\n Ingrese el tamaño del vector 2: ");
    v2=sc.nextInt();
    //Creamos el primer vector con el tamaño de v1
    double vec2[]=new double[v2];
    //recorremos el vector v2 para llenarlo
    for(int i2=0; i2<vec2.length;i2++){
        System.out.print("ingrese el numero de la posicion "+i2+":");
        vec2[i2]=sc.nextDouble();
    }
    /*Determinamos cual de los dos vectores es mas grande,
    para k el vector 3 tenga el tamaño del mas grande*/
    v3=v1;
    if (v2 > v1)
        v3=v2;        
    //Declaramos el vector 3
    double vec3[]=new double[v3];
    //recorremos el vector 3 para hacer la suma
    for(int i3=0;i3<vec3.length;i3++){
        double valv1=0.0;
        if (vec1.length > i3){
            valv1 = vec1[i3];
        }
        double valv2=0.0;
        if(vec2.length > i3){
            valv2=vec2[i3];                
        }
        /*Hacemos la suma de las posiciones de los vectores 1 y 2 en las 
        posiciones del vector 3*/
        vec3[i3]=valv1*valv2;
        System.out.println("\nLa Suma de la Posicion"+" "+i3+" "+ "es:"+vec3[i3]);
    }
}
```

}

Primero el codigo no es mio, lo unico que le he cambiado, desde mi parecer, es el tipo de variable de int a double, debido a que los vectores son decimales.

Si dejo todas las variables como entero el codigo funciona genial, pero, cuando hago el cambio de int a double me dice esto

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at OperacionVectores.main(OperacionVectores.java:40)

Creo que el problema esta luego de la linea que dice v3=v1
muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Que hay en la línea 40?

Comment: He tenido que contar las líneas, y por suerte creo que coincide la linea 40 del mensaje con la que da el error en el código que has pasado, respuesta abajo :)

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo que hay en la linea 40 es esto : if(vec2.length < vec2[i3]){ , aun estoy aprendiendo a usar bien la plataforma. Muchisimas gracias por toda la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que haces la comparación en el if justo al revés de como te interesa, aqui : `if (vec1.length < i3){ valv1 = vec1[i3];}` en `vec1.length < i3` estás diciéndole a tu comparador que haga lo que hay dentro sólo si el índice es mayor que la longitud del vector, cuando lo que te interesa hacer es justo lo contrario:

```
if (vec1.length > i3){ 
    valv1 = vec1[i3];
}
```

Así siempre que el índice sea menor que la longitud del array, operarás con lo que hay dentro, de la otra forma buscas en posiciones que no existen.

**ESPERO QUE TE HAYA SERVIDO :)**

**EDIT => PD:** en las sigientes comparaciones:

```
        Double valv1=0.0;
        if (vec1.length < i3){
            valv1 = vec1[i3];
        }
        Double valv2=0.0;
        if(vec2.length < vec2[i3]){
            valv2=vec2[i3];                
        }
```

Supongo que la finalidad de lo que quieres conseguir es la misma, pero las condiciones no comparan las mismas cosas, la primera condición compara la longitud de un array con el índice a utilizar, en la segunda comparas la longitud de otro array, pero con el valor de la posición `i3` de ese mismo array, solo lo apunto para que lo tengas en cuenta, que seguramente en la segunda comparación querrás hacer lo mismo que en la primera, en cuyo caso, debes hacer el mismo cambio que en la primera comparación :)

Comment: hellos, ya pude dar con todos los pequeños problemitas que tenia mi codigo, modifico el codigo k ya escribi para asi darle la oportunidad de que alguien mas aprenda sobre programacion

Comment: Me alegro de que funcionase la solución que he ofrecido :)